# Should a newly-created tag be propagated to existing questions?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation

Apologies if this has been asked before.  It seems like something that would have come up early on, but I do not see an existing meta question on the subject.

If I create a new tag for a product which seems relevant to the site (e.g., [talend](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talend)), should I run a search and add the tag to existing questions?

Comment: If the questions warrant the tag, then sure, feel free to retag it! However, there's an etiquette in doing mass retagging as explained on [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308429/241919), especially "*do not edit too much posts at once as this will bump a lot of old questions to the front page (less of a problem on a private beta, but it can still be annoying)*"

Comment: @AndrewT. - that should be added as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 6):

> If I create a new tag for a product which seems relevant to the site (e.g., [talend](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talend)), should I run a search and add the tag to existing questions?

#### Yes, this is welcome but please *take your time* and *add as much value as you can* at each stage of the process:

- Avoid making **too many tag edits** in a short period of time. Tag edits bump questions to the top of the home page (when sorted by Active). Others might find this annoying if done too aggressively. A good rule of thumb is to edit around 5 at a time, leaving at least an hour between batches, depending on background site activity levels at the time.
- Watch for and be prepared to address **feedback on meta**. You might have just created an awesome tag that no one had ever thought of before in the site's history. Or, there might be a good reason not to have the tag. This is another good reason not to go nuts adding the new tag; it will be a lot easier to roll back a 5-question tag mistake than a 100-question one.
- **Don't just retag**: Make all the constructive edits you can on each Q & A page you encounter. This will naturally slow down the rate of change, and provide the most lasting value to the site. Improve the question (including the title) where possible, and each answer as well. Flag any obsolete comments you encounter, and move useful content from comments to the parent post wherever appropriate.
- Make sure the **usage guidance** for the new tag exists, and accurately describes how the tag should be used in the context of the site. Simply defining what the tag means is not normally sufficient. A new tag needs unambiguous usage guidance so people know when to (and when not to) add it.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

I think that's an ideal case. More important though would be to contribute to the tag wiki at least a synopsis of what the product or service or company does.

But, yes it's certainly a valid contribution either way.